# How can delete the nodes from array objects if array key match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of keys i want to delete the nodes from array of object.

I have tried but not working

```
if(attr_type === "Blush" || attr_type === "Tie Male"
            || attr_type === "Arm Female Brown"
            || attr_type === "Arm Female Grey"
            || attr_type === "Arm Male Brown"
            || attr_type === "Arm Male Grey"
            || attr_type === "Glasses Or Mask Female"
            || attr_type === "Glasses Or Mask Male"
            || attr_type === "Glasses Or Mask Male For Outfit"
            || attr_type === "Shoes Female"
            || attr_type === "Shoes Male"
            || attr_type === "Boy Shoes"
            || attr_type === "Girl Shoes"
            || attr_type === "Outfit Female Arm Grey"
            || attr_type === "Outfit Female Arm Brown"
            || attr_type === "Pants Female"
            || attr_type === "Pants Male"
        
            ) { 
 
                delete attributes[i];
                  
            }
```

This is script

```
[
 'Blush',
 'Tie Male',
 'Arm Female Brown',
 'Outfit Female Arm Grey'
]
```

This array object

```
 [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Yellow"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Blush",
      "value": "None"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
      "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
    }
    
]
```

This is final array

```
[
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Yellow"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
      "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
    }
    
]
```

The array may be many keys and array object has many nodes.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: I am using delete keyword but it is not working

Comment: please add this to your question

Comment: One way is to use `.filter` on your object-array and filter-out those objects which have `trait_type` that is found in your array-of-keys. Something like so: `const filteredArray = objArray.filter(({trait_type}) => !(keysArray.includes(trait_type)));`

Comment: @gil Question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

i would go this way  -

```js
const keyWords = [
        'Blush',
        'Tie Male',
        'Arm Female Brown',
        'Outfit Female Arm Grey'
    ]
    
    const arr = [
        {
            "trait_type": "Background",
            "value": "Yellow"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Blush",
            "value": "None"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
            "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
        }
    
    ]
    
    
    const keyWordsSet = new Set(keyWords);
    
    console.log(arr.filter(obj => !keyWordsSet.has(obj.trait_type)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
const array1 = [
 'Blush',
 'Tie Male',
 'Arm Female Brown',
 'Outfit Female Arm Grey'
]

const array2 =  [
  {
    "trait_type": "Background",
    "value": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "trait_type": "Blush",
    "value": "None"
  },
  {
    "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
    "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
  }
]

console.log(array2.filter(a2 => !array1.includes(a2.trait_type)))
```

Comment: @raheelaslam please approve this if this works for you. Happy to have an upvote as well

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

**Working Demo :**

```js
const blackList = [
 'Blush',
 'Tie Male',
 'Arm Female Brown',
 'Outfit Female Arm Grey'
];

const inputArr = [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Yellow"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Blush",
      "value": "None"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
      "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
    }
    
];

const res = inputArr.filter((obj) => !blackList.includes(obj.trait_type));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @raheelaslam Kindly do accept if it helps you. So that it will be helpful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const reflist = [
  'Blush',
  'Tie Male',
  'Arm Female Brown',
  'Outfit Female Arm Grey'
]
const arr = [
  {
    "trait_type": "Background",
    "value": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "trait_type": "Blush",
    "value": "None"
  },
  {
    "trait_type": "Body Male Grey",
    "value": "Male Body Grey Color"
  }
];
const output = arr.filter(item => reflist.indexOf(item.trait_type) === -1);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: @raheelaslam please approve this if this works for you. Happy to have an upvote aswell